# Two different value functions formulations, how can I reconcile them?

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I've been studying Reinforcement learning for the past months, and using different sources, I've been seeing different formulations for the same thing. Specifically for value iteration:

[image: first formulation]

[image]

My question is this: imagine that I'm in a scenario where the reward is only dependent on the state, meaning that the reward is for example -1 for all states, with one exception, where it is 1.

For the first formulation the summation will be the:

$V(s)\leftarrow \max _{a}\sum_{_{s'}}p(s'|s, a)[r_{s'} + \gamma V(s')]$, where $r_{s'}$ is the reward for reaching s'

With the second formulation :

$V(s)\leftarrow r_{s}+\max _{a}\sum_{_{s'}}p(s'|s, a)[  \gamma V(s')]$, where $r_s$ is the reward of state s

I'm having trouble reconciling why they are different, shouldn't they produce the same result? I tried them with a very simple RL example where the rewards follow the logic explained above. They produced different policies.

Thank you for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are the same, but the first formula is more general and allows stochastic rewards.

### Remarks

1. $$p(s', r \mid s, a)$$ implies that the reward $r$ is dependent on both a state $s$ and an action $a$.
2. In the first image:$$\sum_{s', r}(\cdot) \overset{\underset{\mathrm{def}}{}}{=} \sum_{s' \in S}\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}}(\cdot)$$.
3. In the second image, $R(s)$ implies that the reward $r$ is solely dependent on a state $s$. This means: $$p(r \mid s, a) = p(r \mid s)$$ for any $s \in S$, $a \in A$, and $r \in \mathbb{R}$.

   1. $p(r | s)$ is $1$ if $R(s) = r$ and $0$ otherwise.
4. In the second image, $P_{sa}(s')$ implies that the state $s'$ is solely dependent on a state $s$ and an action $a$. This means that: $$p(s' \mid s, a, r) = p(s' \mid s, a)$$ since $r$ is dependent on $s$.

With this knowledge, it is possible to derive the second formula from the first.

### Reconciliation

$\begin{align}
V(s) &\leftarrow \max_{a \in A}\sum_{s', r}p(s', r \mid s, a) \cdot [r + \gamma V(s')] \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A}\sum_{s' \in S}\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}}p(s', r \mid s, a) \cdot [r + \gamma V(s')] & \text{(Remark #2)}\\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A}\sum_{s' \in S}\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}}p(s' \mid s, a, r) \cdot p(r \mid s, a) \cdot [r + \gamma V(s')] & \text{(Bayes Theorem)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A}\sum_{s' \in S}\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}}p(s' \mid s, a, r) \cdot p(r \mid s) \cdot [r + \gamma V(s')] & \text{(Remark #3)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A}\sum_{s' \in S}\sum_{r \in \mathbb{R}}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot p(r \mid s) \cdot [r + \gamma V(s')] & \text{(Remark #4)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A}\sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot [R(s) + \gamma V(s')] & \text{(Remark #3.1)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A} \left[ \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot R(s) + \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot \gamma V(s')\right] & \text{(law of distribution)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A} \left[ R(s) \cdot \sum_{s' \in S} p(s' \mid s, a) + \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot \gamma V(s')\right] & \text{(Pull out } R(s) \text{)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A} \left[ R(s) \cdot (1) + \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot \gamma V(s')\right] & \text{(A law of probabilities)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A} \left[ R(s) + \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot \gamma V(s')\right] & \text{(Simplification)} \\
&\leftarrow \max_{a \in A} R(s) + \max_{a \in A} \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot \gamma V(s') & \text{(max{a + b} = max{a} + max{b})} \\
&\leftarrow R(s) + \max_{a \in A} \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot \gamma V(s') & \text{(}R(s) \text{ is not dependent on } a \text{)}\\
V(s) &\leftarrow R(s) + \max_{a \in A} \gamma \sum_{s' \in S}p(s' \mid s, a) \cdot V(s') & \text{(Pull out } \gamma \text{)}\\
\end{align}$

which is the second formula.

Comment: Thank you @ljeabmreosn  I'm much appreciated for you careful answer. I got the results you explained. But now, seeing it from the new perspective you just gave me It raised me another doubt. It has to due with the concept of immediate reward, in here it is like we are saying that the the immediate reward of  being in s and applying a is the reward assigned to state S. Shouldn't the immediate reward be the reward of state s'. It makes more sense, because is the reward that we actually observe after the transition.

Comment: @Tomé Silva - No. The immediate reward is the reward for being in the current state s. If the reward is also dependent on the action as well as the current state, then the immediate reward is the reward for being in state s and taking action a. There is a good question on this topic in one of David Silver's RL lectures: https://youtu.be/lfHX2hHRMVQ